# Unable to run Get-WmiObject on machine connected via Direct Connect VPN

Tags: powershell, wmi, vpn

```
$adminaccount = "DOMAIN\USERNAME"
$PASSWORD = ConvertTo-SecureString "PASSWORD" -AsPlainText -Force
$UNPASSWORD = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential $adminaccount, $PASSWORD

$Machines = Get-Content -Path "C:\Temp\production computers.txt"

$Result = Foreach ($Machine in $Machines){
New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
$hardware =  Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $Machine -Credential $UNPASSWORD
$os =  Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $Machine -Credential $UNPASSWORD
Computer = $Machine
Manufacturer = $hardware.Manufacturer
Model = $hardware.Model
OS = $os.Caption
}| Select-Object Computer,Manufacturer,Model,OS
}

$Result | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Temp\pcsinventory.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Trying to run the above to gather information from a list of machines, got two issues: Firstly I can get information back from machines connected to the network directly but the machines we have on Direct Connect VPNs get an "unable to contact RPC Server" error from the Get-WmiObjectcommand ; Secondly the results I do get seem to all come out as the same, when I know they're different, so somethings going wrong there.

Comment: Is it possible there's a FW issue given the different network paths?  You should try `Get-CimInstance` instead of `Get-WmiObject`.  The latter is deprecated and removed from the latest versions of PoSh.  One of the reasons is the underlying DCOM/RPC protocols aren't FW friendly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using CIM cmdlets instead of legacy `Get-WMIObject`. In this case, `Get-CimInstance` can be a direct substitute.

I'm guessing there's a firewall issue given the different network paths. `Get-WMIObject is deprecated in Windows PowerShell and removed from PowerShell Core.

Straight forward example:

```
$adminaccount = "DOMAIN\USERNAME"
$PASSWORD     = ConvertTo-SecureString "PASSWORD" -AsPlainText -Force
$UNPASSWORD   = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential $adminaccount, $PASSWORD
$hwProps      = 'manufacturer','Model'

$Machines = Get-Content -Path "C:\Temp\production computers.txt"

$Result = Foreach ($Machine in $Machines){
    $hw =  Get-CimInstance Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $Machine -Property $hwProps -Credential $UNPASSWORD
    $os =  Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $Machine -Credential $UNPASSWORD
    
    [PSCustomObject]@{    
        Computer     = $Machine
        Manufacturer = $hw.Manufacturer
        Model        = $hw.Model
        OS           = $os.Caption
    }
}

$Result | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Temp\pcsinventory.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

I changed a little syntax, using the newer `[PSCustomObject]` casting.  I also moved the I  WMI queries out of the custom object declaration. They don't need to be there, and by doing so you don't need the `Select-Object` command.  This is because now the only properties in the object are the ones you would have selected anyway.

Even if Cim doesn't solve the problem it's really the way to go.  Take a look at [Introduction to CIM CMdlets](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/introduction-to-cim-cmdlets/) which will give you a good start...

Update to use Credentials with CIM:

```
$adminaccount = "DOMAIN\USERNAME"
$PASSWORD     = ConvertTo-SecureString "PASSWORD" -AsPlainText -Force
$UNPASSWORD   = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential $adminaccount, $PASSWORD
$hwProps      = 'manufacturer','Model'

$Machines = Get-Content -Path "C:\Temp\production computers.txt"

$Result = Foreach ($Machine in $Machines){
    $CimSession = New-CimSession -ComputerName $Machine -Credential $UNPASSWORD
    $hw =  Get-CimInstance Win32_ComputerSystem -CimSession $CimSession -Property $hwProps
    $os =  Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem -CimSession $CimSession
    
    [PSCustomObject]@{    
        Computer     = $Machine
        Manufacturer = $hw.Manufacturer
        Model        = $hw.Model
        OS           = $os.Caption
    }
}

$Result | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Temp\pcsinventory.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Update above uses `New-CimSession` with the `-Credential` parameter.  Then it specs the`-CimSession $CimSession` instead of `-ComputerName...`.  The credentials were overlooked in my initial example. Note: Using a CIM session is actually more efficient than repeating commands with `-ComputerName...`. The latter creates a CIM session under the hood, so each iteration creates and tears down a session, by reusing a session you do that fewer times...

Comment: There is a known issue with the class `Win32_ComputerSystem` and `Get-CIMInstance` - one of the things it returns in that class is a bitmap for the OEM logo, and this causes `Get-CIMInstance` to fail where `Get-WMIObject` does not. The only workaround to this is to specify the specific object properties you are interested in when you call `Get-CimInstance`.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that, thanks for the heads-up.  Locally the OEMLogoBitmap isn't returning for me. There's little harm in narrowing the returned properties.  I edited the sample as such.  Of course a side benefit of this is the returning data should be smaller, should make a slight improvement to performance.

Comment: Thanks for that, the syntax clean-up seems to have sorted out the dupliction of results I was getting, I cannot however seem to get `Get-CimInstance` to work at all even on the machines where `Get-WmiObject` was working previously. One obvious error is that `Get-CimInstance` doesn't accept a -Credentials switch. I'll keep pluggin away with CIM til something sticks!

Comment: Sorry I missed the creds. I added a second example with additional comments to get you past that.  Let me know how it goes.

Comment: OK so the latest update on this, I've got the `New-CimSession` working and getting information back when I do it from a machine to a domain controller but I can't get it to connect back the other way. It's definitely firewall trickery of some sort, although we do have the domain firewall turned of via GP!

Comment: GP is Global Protect? Also, how many computers are you querying?